# Drop annotation on map

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite, mkmapview

Can any one
My trying different-different View for droping annotation on the map But not getting success.This is my last try .
Can any one help me out from this condition .
How can I Show annotation on the map .
By retrieving the annotation data(long,latit) from Sqlite data base .
I have 10 to 15 data in Sqlite table .I To want display annotation to map on this data(long,latit).
My data is like that

1. 42.338326,-71.131411
2. 42.338347,-71.131647
3. 42.33838,-71.131861
4. 42.338551,-71.132934
5. 42.338573,-71.13302
6. 42.338594,-71.133213
7. 42.338626,-71.133406
8. 42.338809,-71.134393

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do few more things like, 1) Adding annotations to map view and 2) Implementing `viewForAnnotation:` method. [Follow this tutorial](http://iphonebcit.wordpress.com/iphone-map-kit-tutorial/iphone-map-kit-tutorial2/).

Comment: Read [`this piece`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW1) from Apple's documentation too.

Comment: @Deepak I have the annotation coordinate value in the sqlite data base And i want use that data displaying annotation on the map.

Comment: So is your problem getting the data off the database?

Comment: @Deepak Yes i am trying to get data from the sqlite database And diplay on to the map as annotation

Comment: Update the question as such and show your current code. Only then can we tell you what you are doing wrong right now.

Comment: @Deepak finally I done with photo annotation But How can do for comment annotation ,video annotation and the bookmark annotation

Answer (score 1):

I was able to set up my map view by following this tutorial: http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/mapkit-example-in-iphone/

I think it will help you a lot.

Comment: my program flow is like that Map class > Photo Class >Map class .The annotation data(Coordinate) come from sqlite dataBase .I want to know how can I take value from data base and display at map as annotation